# Tensorflow Build from Source Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I am trying to follow these installation instructions https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_rpi.

When I try to "cross-compile the TensorFlow source code to build a Python pip package", I get the error message: Command "CI_DOCKER_EXTRA_PARAMS" is unknown.

This is the command:

```
CI_DOCKER_EXTRA_PARAMS="-e CI_BUILD_PYTHON=python3 -e CROSSTOOL_PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/python3.4" \
```

The host computer: 
Windows 10 Pro Version 1909
Python 3.8.2
pip 20.1
virtualenv 20.0.20

Also the test command for Docker works fine:

```
docker run --rm hello-world
"Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly."
```

Does anyone have an idea or a tip? I suspect something is not installed properly. Is "CI_DOCKER_EXTRA_PARAMS" a Docker-command? What is the requirement for the OS to know or recognize this command?

Comment: _I get the error message: Command "CI_DOCKER_EXTRA_PARAMS" is unknown._ Is that all the output?

Comment: This is the full output: "The command "CI_DOCKER_EXTRA_PARAMS" is either misspelled or could not be found"

Comment: You absolutely must build TF from source?

Comment: Well, as I understand it, that's the recommended way to get started with Tensorflow on the RPi. Isn't it?

Comment: What would you recommend for this? I just want to get started with TF on RPi.

Comment: Well, unless I'm misunderstanding something, you should be able to install it like any other pip package. The page you linked to contains the following: _Note: We already provide well-tested, pre-built [TensorFlow packages](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) for Raspbian systems._